# Identifying recipients with errors in send log

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, logging, login-errors

Based on  Markus Slabina's great [article](https://markus.codes/2017/07/20/unleash-the-power-of-send-logging-in-marketing-cloud) I set up a send log for my Marketing Cloud.
To enrich the standard send log data, I have added a snippet of AMP script to all my emails which allows me to bring in additional info such as subscriber key, email address, email name and timestamp.

```
%%[VAR @DataExtension, @EmailName SET @DataExtension = _DataSourceName
 SET @EmailName = emailname_ SET @SubscriberKey = _subscriberkey SET 
@EmailAddress = emailaddr Set @EventDate = Now() ]%%
```

Everything works as expected when emails are sent successfully but when any of them errors the only info which seems to get logged is the ErrorCode and TriggeredSendID. Obviously, none of these two data points are recipient specific which means that I am left in the dark about which user is affected by the error.

I know that I can always check the timestamp of a record before and after to narrow down the time frame and combining it with TrigeredSendID most of the time would be enough to pin point the recipient, but I was wondering whether anyone can suggest more scalable way of going about it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and [official documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/) I can assume that values are not get logged into the SendLogin data extension because they don't have values at the time error occurs (or they are not counted in the internal error handling routine). Therefore, there is nothing to write into the respective fields except ErrorCode and TriggerSendID at that time. Since SendLogging is an internal feature of SFMC, its hard to say how exactly it handles exceptions. I am not sure that it is even feasible what you want with AMPscript, but you might want to check this out with Support.